# How do I use DMA in a macOS Kext?

Tags: macos, pci, kernel-extension, driverkit

I've been working on making a kext to access data on PCI BAR memory. Currently I am able to map the data and access it but its very slow. I'd like to use DMA to increase the speed at which I can communicate with the device, however I've been unable to find many good examples. I was looking at this page (https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOPCIFamily/IOPCIFamily-106/AppleSamplePCI/AppleSamplePCI.cpp.auto.html) but I'm unsure what should be placed where it says "if we had a DMA controller, kick off the DMA here." Does anyone have any good resources they would be willing to share?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking here. DMA is generally triggered in a device-specific fashion. So, you memory-map a BAR (`mapDeviceMemoryWithRegister()` and friends); this "memory" will correspond to device registers, and you will typically bit-bang on these device registers to make the device do *something*, including performing DMA transfers. The layout and semantics of these registers are entirely device specific.

Incidentally, your question is tagged with the `kernel-extension` tag, but I should point out that PCI driver kernel extensions are now deprecated and it's possible to write PCI drivers using DriverKit. (Though not necessarily **all** kinds of PCI device drivers, the vast majority can now be done in user space.)